# How to tell if all of a certain node are gone in Sprite-Kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, nodes

I'm creating this app (written in objective-c) and everything has gone well up to this point, I cannot fathom how to create the code that would check to see if all of a certain node (whose name isEqualToString:@"someName"];) are removed from the scene, and after it finds out that there are no more nodes in the scene with that name, then refresh the scene (I know how to refresh the scene). I'm looking for a bit of code that can be put in an "if" statement (like "if the nodes are gone, refresh the scene).

Any ideas would be a monumental help because I have not been able to find anything online to help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `childNodeWithName` function to check for a `node` with a particular name. If its `nil`, then its not in the hierarchy.

In **Swift**

```
if self.childNodeWithName("someName") == nil {

    println("not present")
}
```

In **ObjectiveC**

```
if ([self childNodeWithName:@"someName"] == nil) {

    NSLog(@"Not present");
}
```

Comment: First off, thank you for the response, second, is that written in Swift? I don't recognize println and when I incorporate that code in my program (written in objective c) it gives me errors. I just tried: if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"someName"] == nil){ //code} but that just gave me a warning saying something like "Comparison between pointer and integer."